# After update to 6.5 no users except Administrator in Administration/Security/Users

Tags: sonarqube

I have 40 users in my sonarqube instance.
After updating to Sonarqube 6.5 in Administration/Security/Users there is only Administrator.
Sonarqube connected to PostgreSQL database and table ***users*** contains all 40 users. Also they can login. Creating missing users fails with message: **An active user with login 'XXXX' already exists**.

I tried `REINDEX DATABASE sonarqube;` with no result.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of users is by default not shown completely in newer versions of SonarQube. Start typing a user's name or email in the **filter** input box to find the users you are looking for.

While a list of 40 users would be easy to display, some instances of SonarQube have thousands of users. The new behaviour of the user list improves the user experience on such systems.

---

Side note: If an unexpected error occurred during startup you indeed might have to **reindex** the database once. To do this stop SonarQube, make a backup of everything, remove the `data/es` directory and start SonarQube again.

Comment: Solution with removing **data\es** folder have solved my problem. Thanks a lot.